# Extracting text from a PDF file using PyPDF2

Tags: python-3.x, pypdf

This is my first question here so I apologise if it ends up in the wrong place or I miss any valuable info. I am also incredibly new to coding & python in general.

I'm using Python 3.7.4 (v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 14:54:52)

I'm trying to write some code that will extract all the text from a PDF file and place it in a value (I know, simple stuff!).

I have managed to get this to work without issue on a 1 page pdf, but when trying on a 96 page PDF I am only getting the first and last page extracted to the value. This is the code I'm using:

```
pdfFile2 = open('/filepath/ir-2030.pdf', 'rb')
irReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile2)

pageNum2 = str(irReader.numPages)
print('Your document has ' + pageNum2 + ' pages' + '\n')

for pN in range(irReader.numPages):
    ir2030 = irReader.getPage(pN).extractText()

print(ir2030)
```

I have used almost identical coding previously and it worked without issue but for a reason unbeknownst to me, I'm only getting a return of page 1 and 96 of the pdf document from the `print(ir2030)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated or if there is a better way of doing what I'm trying to do...

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every iteration, you reset the value of `ir2030`. Maybe append the values to a list?

```
ir2030s = []
for pN in range(irReader.numPages):
    ir2030s.append(irReader.getPage(pN).extractText())

print(ir2030)
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
ir2030s = [irReader.getPage(pN).extractText() for pN in range(irReader.numPages)]
```